# How to train OpenNLP for non-English languages?

Tags: opennlp, named-entity-recognition

Is it possible to train OpenNLP for languages different than English like Slavic languages written in cyrillic, using OpenNLP API ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. The OpenNLP documentation provides instructions on how to use and train each one of the modules.

For named entity recognition specifically, please see [here](http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/manual/opennlp.html#tools.namefind.training).